# Is there any fee for amending claims before the publication in USPTO?

Tags: claims, uspto, claim-amendment

My USPTO non-provisional application is not published yet. It contains 1 independent claim and 19 dependant claims.

I would like to remove some dependent claims and then add some new claims. The updated version would look like 2 independent claims and 18 dependent claims.

Is there any fee I have to pay for making such amendments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no fee for filing a claim amendment. The only fees that might pertain to this are excess claim fees. In your scenario you end up at the 20 maximum claims and below the 3 independent claims. You an amend before publication and/or after publication.